# JQUERY fancybox launch onclick

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(
   function(){
        $('#button').click(function() {
        $("#content_of_fancybox").fancybox({
            'scrolling'     : 'no',
            'titleShow'     : false
        });
        });
   }
);
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="button" value=" Open fancybox " id="button">

<div id="content_of_fancybox" style="width: 400px; margin: 0; display: none;">
Hello pandas!
</div>
```

The fancybox should open when user clicks on the button, but it doesn't. What is the error (I guess it's in the javascript part)?

Comment: what is the error? (message etc)

Comment: @Neal Well, the fancybox doesn't open at all.

Comment: see my update about a dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox works on click of the object that you attach the fancybox to: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/WbCMV/2/

---

If you want a dialog just use [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/WbCMV/4/

Comment: @Neal fancybox certainly works with a good many DOM elements. It is just a slightly unintuitive way to get it set up. Check http://fancybox.net/howto out

Comment: No it actually does work with divs, but it is more complicated to get set up.

Comment: @Neal But I want fancybox to work as a confirmation box when submitting my form, so the way you are using it isn't really convenient to my case

Comment: @AdamStrudwick, you cannot do that. use a jQuery dialog instead. one minute ill make a fiddle

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll use the dialog, it's more intuitive

Comment: @AdamStrudwick -- no problemo ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Adam, I was confused when I started working with fancybox as well, but I suggest you look at the documentation. When you call the actual fancybox function on something, it simply sets that part of the page up to be popped up within a fancybox. It does NOT pop it up upon calling of the function. Basically what your code is doing is SETTING UP the DOM element with ID content_of_fancybox to pop up in a fancybox when you click the DOM element with id of button. From there if you had an anchor tag correctly formatted then you could click on it and your content would display in a "Fancybox."

Follow the steps found here http://fancybox.net/howto to get it set up and working!

Here is a JS fiddle that has it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/GU7W9/